# Calling in an external SWF. How to Pre-load?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloader

I have a project where clicking on one of a series of spots on an object will pull in a SWF file related to that particular spot. (Think of a car; clicking on the engine will load the engine.swf and clicking on the wheel will load wheel.swf).

Do I add a pre-loader to the Main timeline or do I add one that plays immediately on the external SWFs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a preloader to the Main Timeline, if you add it to the external SWF , it will not start playing until that swf is loaded which defeats the purpose.

In the MainTimeline, your preloader will react as soon as the loading process starts, i.e. when the size of the swf to be loaded is known ( bytesTotal ).